# read a closed tag from xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have made something that reads from an xml file it all works perfectly.
but there is one thing that wont work.

this is the xml part that works fine

```
<title>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</title>
```

this is the xml part i want to read:

```
 <enclosure url="http://media.nu.nl/m/m1nxf1eaa6mh_sqr256.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
```

i only want the url in a variable.

and this is what i have so far:

```
switch (node.Name)
                {
                    case "title": label5.Text = (node.InnerText); break;
                    case "enclosure": string picbox2 = (node.InnerText); break;
                        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = picbox2;
                    case "description": label6.Text = (node.InnerText); i++; break;

                }
```

i hope i have provided enough information.

Comment: Those are called attributes. Do a search for reading XML node attributes in C# and you'll be well on your way.

Comment: Pay attention to the position of the `break` as to why the presented code causes a compiler error ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the "enclosure" case, you have an assignment statement: `pictureBox2.ImageLocation = picbox2;` after the case's `break;` statement. I would not expect this to compile.

You also need to access element attributes as `element.Attributes["attr_name"].Value` rather than using the InnerText property which will bring back the text between the opening and closing element tags.

```
switch (node.Name)
{
    case "title": 
        label5.Text = (node.InnerText); 
        break;
    case "enclosure": 
        string picbox2 = (node.Attributes["url"].Value); 
        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = picbox2;
        break;
    case "description": 
        label6.Text = (node.InnerText); 
        i++; 
        break;

}
```